# Finding $x\in k^3$ such that no component of $Ax$ is zero

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and let $n\geq 1$. Let $A\in \operatorname{Mat}(n\times 3,k)$ be a matrix such that no row of $A$ is zero. I would like to find $x,y,z\in k$ such that no component of $A(x,y,z)^{t}$ is zero.

I think proceeding by induction should work. For $n=1$ this is not a problem. But how do I go from $n-1$ to $n$? Suppose we are given $x,y,z\in k$ such that $xa_i+yb_i+zc_i=0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$, where $(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ is the $i$th row of $A$. I have to adjust $x,y,z$ in such a way that we also have $xa_n+yb_n+zc_n=0$.

$\textbf{Edit}$ As Robert posted below, this is false in general. What about if $k$ is algebraically closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: over the field $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ let $$A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1\cr  0 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 0}$$

EDIT: If $k$ is algebraically closed, in particular it has infinite degree over the field $k_A$ generated by the entries of $A$. Letting $x$, $y$, $z$ be members of $k$ 
linearly independent over $k_A$, each entry of $A \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr z}$ is
a linear combination of $x, y, z$ over $k_A$ with coefficients not all $0$,
and therefore is not $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I am mainly interested in $k$ being algebraically closed, should have said that. Have you got any idea on how to proceed in this case?